# OpenGL buffer swap refresh rate, how to calculate ideal

Tags: android, linux, opengl-es

I am timing my OpenGL frame rates, with v-sync turned on, and notice my timings aren't the precise frequency as set by the monitor.  That is, on my desktop I have a 60Hz refresh, but the FPS is stable at 59.88, whereas on my tablet it's also 60Hz but the FPS can be 61/62 FPS. I'm curious as to what precisely causes these slight deviations.

These are the ideas I've had so far:

1. Dropped Frames: This is the obvious answer: I'm just missing some frames. This is however not the cause as I can verify I am not dropping frames and the drop in FPS would be higher if this happened.  I calculate the time over 120 frames, so if 1 frame was lost the FPS would drop below 59.5 on the desktop.
2. Inaccurate timings: I use clock_gettime to get my timings. On Linux I know this is accurate enough (as I previously did nanosecond based timings with it, but here we could even live with +/- several hundred microseconds). On Android however I'm not sure of the accuracy of this.
3. API Oddity: I use glXSwapBuffers on the desktop and eglSwapBuffers on Android. There could be an oddity here, but I don't see how this could so subtley affect the frame rate.
4. Approximate Hz: This is my biggest guess that the video cards/monitor aren't actually running at 60Hz. This is probably tied to the exact speed of the monitor, and the video card frequency. This seems like something that could be concretely determined, but I don't know which tools can be used to do this. (Update: My current video mode in Linux shows  59.93Hz, so closer, but still not there)

If the answer is indeed #4 this is perhaps not the best exchange site for the question. But in all cases my ultimate goal is to figure out programmatically what the ideal refresh rate actaully is. So I'm hoping somebody can confirm/deny my ideas, and possibly point me in the right direction to getting the information I need.